# The field was not set error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I get field was not set error when I'm validating a form

Here is my view

```
<div class="panel-body">

    <h3>Basic Information</h3>

<?php $atrrib = array('class' => 'form-horizontal','role' => 'form');?>
<?php echo form_open('school/shule',$atrrib);?>
<div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="add_name" class="col-md-2 control-label">School:</label> 
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="add_name" id="addSchoolName" placeholder="School name">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
<?php echo form_close();?> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2"><?php include_once (APPPATH. 'views/admin/admin_right_column.php');?></div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller

class School extends CI_Controller {

```
  public function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
 }// End of construct

 public function shule(){
     $this->load->library('form_validation');

        if($this->form_validation->run('first_form') === TRUE){

            echo 'Valid';
        }

        else{
         if(validation_errors()){

           echo validation_errors();

         }  

     $data['title'] = "Add School";
     $data['page'] = "admin| add school";


     $this->load->view('admin/admin_header',$data);
     $this->load->view('admin/add_school',$data);
     $this->load->view('admin/admin_footer');  
     }

 }
```

}

Here is my form_validation configuration

```
               $config['first_form'] = array(
                array(
                  'field' => 'add_name',
                  'label' => 'School name',
                  'rules' => 'required|xss_clean|min_length[2]' 
                )
             );
```

I get an field was not set error when I left the field blank and also I get an Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name error when I input a single char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried looking where CI fire up your error

> Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name

Then I found this

```
        if ($result === FALSE)
        {
            if ( ! isset($this->_error_messages[$rule]))
            {
                if (FALSE === ($line = $this->CI->lang->line($rule)))
                {
                    $line = 'Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name.';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $line = $this->_error_messages[$rule];
            }
```

So this means CI checks if you have not set rule message to the field then check if there is a line that corresponds to the fired function/rule in the form_validation_lang.php file .
So I assumed CI does not find the error message corresponding to your field name because

- You have edited/deleted line with the name of the callback/rule
- You have created another language file under /application/language with the same name as the default form_validation_lang and haven't defined the rule corresponding to your field name .

Solution is to cross check your lang file if it has a line defined with the same name as your rule or delete any custom language file that has the same name as form_validation_lang.php or you can add up a rule such as

```
$lang['required'] = 'Name field is required";
```

or any other rule you have defined in your validation file/function in your custom language file .

Comment: Hi, Robby. Thank you for your answer. Well,I have other forms which works fine although I've define a custom error language file. I've deleted it and this other form now works. Can account for that?

Comment: Yes you can..  wel you can have a custom one that defines all your rules with the same name as the original one..  glady it worked out..

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('add_name', 'School name', 'trim|required||min_length[2]');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
  echo 'Valid';
}
else {
  $data['title'] = "Add School";
  $data['page'] = "admin| add school";
  $this->load->view('admin/admin_header',$data);
  $this->load->view('admin/add_school',$data);
  $this->load->view('admin/admin_footer');
}
```

and check for errors on view

```
if(validation_errors()){
  echo validation_errors();
}
```

Comment: Ok. Let me do that. I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: Sorry shortly took hours. I've been able to find the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom error message with set_message and use the label from the set_rules function. You can find the documentation here.

Here is an example:

```
// Set the validation rule
$this->form_validation->set_rules('project_name', 'Project Name', 'trim|required');

// Set the custom message with %s where the label should go
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s is required. Please enter a value.');

// For an invalid project_name, you will get the error:
// Project Name is required. Please enter a value.
```